# Does time evolution preserve parity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, time-evolution, parity

Let $\psi(t_0, \cdot)$ be the state of a quantum system corresponding to a Hamiltonian $H$ in the position representation at time $t_0$. Assume $\psi(t_0, -x) = \psi(t_0,x)$, that is $\psi(t_0, \cdot)$ is symmetric. Is then $\psi(t, \cdot)$ symmetric for every time $t$? Or in other words: Is $$(e^{-itH}\psi)(t_0, -x)=(e^{-itH}\psi)(t_0, x)?$$ If not, can there be some conditions on $H$ such that this holds?

Comment: The statement of the question is quite garbled, but, a parity-invariant Hamiltonian will  propagate a parity symmetric state to one such at all times in the future. In all representations.

Comment: @CosmasZachos What is "garbled" about the statement of the question? How do you define a parity-invariant Hamiltonian?

Comment: Your "Assume..."  formula has all times. A Parity invariant hamiltonian is $P H P^{-1}=H$ where $P= \exp ( \pi \hat x \hat p /\hbar)$.

Comment: [xkcd: (](https://xkcd.com/859/).

Comment: Correction: the Hermitian phase definition dictates $P=\exp(\pi(\hat x \hat p+\hat p\hat x)/2\hbar)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, let's first define the parity flip operator $P : \mathcal H \rightarrow \mathcal H$, such that it flips the sign of $x$ for any position eigenvector:

$$P |x \rangle \equiv |-x \rangle\qquad (\mathrm{I})$$

Note that $P$ is a Hermitian operator, since the matrix elements $\langle x'| P | x \rangle  = \langle x' | -x \rangle = \delta(x+x')$ are invariant under a conjugate transpose. It's also in fact unitary, but that's not very important here.

Now the assumption of the initial state $|\psi(t_0) \rangle$ being symmetric simply translates to:

$$P|\psi(t_0)\rangle = |\psi(t_0)\rangle \qquad (\mathrm{II})$$

This is because:

$$P|\psi(t_0)\rangle = P \int_{\mathbb R} dx \ \psi(t_0,x) \ |x \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R} dx \ \psi(t_0,x) \ P|x \rangle=\int_{\mathbb R} dx \ \psi(t_0,x) \ |-x \rangle=\int_{\mathbb R} dx \ \psi(t_0,-x) \ |x \rangle$$

which together with $(*)$ implies:

$$\int_{\mathbb R} dx \ \psi(t_0,-x) \ |x \rangle=\int_{\mathbb R} dx \ \psi(t_0,x) \ |x \rangle \Leftrightarrow \psi(t_0,-x)=\psi(t_0,x)$$

With that equivalent statement in mind, let's now look at the Schrodinger equation:

$$i \hbar \frac{d}{dt} |\psi(t) \rangle = H |\psi(t) \rangle$$

Now transform both sides with $P$:

$$i \hbar \frac{d}{dt} P|\psi(t) \rangle = PH |\psi(t) \rangle \qquad (\mathrm{III})$$

where I exchanged the order of $d/dt$ and $P$, since $P$ is a time-independent operator. Now inserting $\mathbb I =P^{-1} P$ into the left side of (III) gives:

$$i \hbar \frac{d}{dt} P|\psi(t) \rangle = PH \ \mathbb I \ |\psi(t) \rangle$$

$$i \hbar \frac{d}{dt} P|\psi(t) \rangle = (PHP^{-1}) \ P |\psi(t) \rangle \qquad (\mathrm{IV})$$

Eq.(IV) tells you how the symmetry properties of the system's state evolve with time under a specific Hamiltonian. For instance, if the Hamiltonian commuted with the parity flip operator, we would have:

$$H P = P H$$

i.e.

$$PHP^{-1} = H$$

Under this assumption, eq.(IV) gives:

$$i \hbar \frac{d}{dt} P|\psi(t) \rangle = H  P |\psi(t) \rangle$$

Now since the initial state is symmetric $P|\psi(t_0) \rangle = |\psi(t_0) \rangle$, and the Schrodinger equation has a unique solution for a specific initial state, we conclude that:

$$P |\psi(t) \rangle = |\psi(t) \rangle \qquad t \in [t_0,+\infty)$$

Meaning that:

**the symmetry of the initial state is preserved throughout the evolution if the Hamiltonian commutes with the generator of that symmetry.**

As an aside, also note the very deep observation that since $[P,H] = 0$, the expectation value of $P$ (which is an observable, since it's Hermitian) is a constant of motion! This is because by the [Ehrenfest theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem):

$$i \hbar \frac{d}{dt} \langle P \rangle = \langle [P,H] \rangle = 0$$

This is a very deep and general result, which is not at all limited to the particular symmetry that was considered here. Any symmetry in the dynamics of a quantum system corresponds to a symmetry generating operator that commutes with the Hamiltonian, and is associated with an observable that is conserved throughout the evolution.